# 0.07s query on MySQL takes 11.68s on MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization, explain

There is different hardware involved (MySQL is on my laptop, MariaDB on the server) but usually the difference is at most 2x not 166x!

The tables contain the same data on each instance (18,000 rows in _cache_card and 157,000 rows in card_legality).

## THE QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM _cache_card AS c 
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT card_id FROM card_legality WHERE format_id = 35);
```

## EXPLAIN

MariaDB:

```
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table         | type | possible_keys                   | key       | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>   | ALL  | distinct_key                    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL  |  9414 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | c             | ALL  | NULL                            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL  | 18567 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | card_legality | ref  | format_id,idx_card_id_format_id | format_id | 4       | const |  9414 |                                                 |
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys                   | key        | key_len | ref        | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | c             | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                            | NULL       | NULL    | NULL       | 18055 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2>   | NULL       | eq_ref | <auto_key>                      | <auto_key> | 4       | cards.c.id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | card_legality | NULL       | ref    | format_id,idx_card_id_format_id | format_id  | 4       | const      | 37828 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

## CREATE TABLE

Both:

```
CREATE TABLE `card_legality` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `card_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `format_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `legality` varchar(190) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `format_id` (`format_id`),
  KEY `idx_card_id_format_id` (`card_id`,`format_id`,`legality`),
  CONSTRAINT `card_legality_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`) REFERENCES `card` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `card_legality_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`format_id`) REFERENCES `format` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1190863 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

(The output here is character-for-character identical.)

MariaDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `_cache_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `layout` varchar(190) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `face_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mana_cost` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmc` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `power` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `toughness` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `loyalty` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_text` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_name` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hand` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `life` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `starter` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_ascii` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_id` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `names` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `legalities` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pd_legal` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bugs` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_name_name` (`name`(142))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `_cache_card` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `layout` varchar(190) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `face_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `mana_cost` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `cmc` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `power` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `toughness` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `loyalty` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `type` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `search_text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `image_name` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `hand` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `life` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `starter` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `position` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `name_ascii` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `card_id` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `names` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `legalities` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `pd_legal` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bugs` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  KEY `idx_name_name` (`name`(142))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

## OTHER DETAILS

MariaDB:

```
version=10.2.16-MariaDB
optimizer_switch=index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on
```

MySQL:

```
version=5.7.17
optimizer_switch=index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on
```

## ADDING INDEX ON card_legality(format_id,card_id)

This somehow makes things *slower*.

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_format_id_card_id ON card_legality(format_id,card_id);
```

Now above 15s.

EXPLAIN (on MariaDB) says:

```
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table         | type | possible_keys                               | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>   | ALL  | distinct_key                                | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL  | 16942 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | c             | ALL  | NULL                                        | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL  | 17653 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | card_legality | ref  | idx_card_id_format_id,idx_format_id_card_id | idx_format_id_card_id | 4       | const | 16942 | Using index                                     |
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: As lukasz implied, this is probably an effect of how MySQL and MariaDB (which actually work quite differently under the hood in some areas) deal with the problem that you do not have an index on `(format_id, card_id)` . This will specifically depend on `version` and `optimizer_switch`es, so could you add those details? And a remark: Your table looks like an `n:m`-relationship (if `(card_id,format_id)` is unique/could make a primary key); changing your pk would probably also solve this issue (although it's probably too late to change the design, or you have other reasons to use this).

Comment: I added the version and optimizer_switch info to the original question. (card_id,format_id) is unique and changing the PK is an option. I have always superstitiously added a single column PK to tables like this in case I later need to refer to it although in this case I'm not really sure when that would be. Would you advise against that in general or is it too situationally dependent to have a general rule?

Comment: You can always refer to a row with the primary key, even if it is a composite key, you do not need to use single-column-autoincrement-value for that. So I would wait until you get to a case where you need it (and then ask myself 10 times if I really need it) and not vice versa, but that might be just personal preference. But while that only might have consequences for execution speed, not specifying your columns as unique might cause actual problems; so even if you prefer to use an autoincrement pk, I would strongly suggest to make sure to add unique keys where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why MariaDB currently uses this suboptimal execution plan. It might be assuming something wrong about your data distribution (although I am not really sure in which case that would be the optimal plan). It might help to use `optimize table card_legality, _cache_card;` to fix the statistics.

If it doesn't, and since we established in the comments that `(card_id,format_id)` is unique, I would try to add the following index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_card_legality ON card_legality(format_id, card_id)
```

and use

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM _cache_card AS c
JOIN card_legality l FORCE INDEX (uidx_card_legality)
ON l.card_id = c.id AND l.format_id = 35;
```

This is basically the way that MySQL currently executes your query (while creating this index on the fly), although you seem to have tried that index with Lukasz' answer and it didn't work.

You should remove `force index` (it is just to make absolutely sure MariaDB has no wiggle room to do something else) and check if MariaDB/MySQL still uses it. Also test what happens for other values of `format_id`, as `35` might be an outlier (e.g. you may just have a handful of entries for that format), and optimizing the execution plan for this might slow down the query for all other values. And of course make sure that you are comparing similar resultsets, as if MariaDB has e.g. 10k entries for format 35, while MySQL has none, that would not be a fair fight.

Comment: OPTIMIZE said `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead` for both.

BUUUUUUT adding the UNIQUE key drops the time of the query on production to 0.09 seconds! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would add index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON card_legality(format_id, card_id);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=96538c2a8c28d3f58904409584b183f9)**

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM _cache_card AS c 
WHERE c.id IN (SELECT card_id FROM card_legality WHERE format_id = 35);
               -- covering index created before
```

Comment: Somehow this makes things slower?! Up above 15s now. I did a few runs to make sure I wasn't going crazy. Is this functionally the same thing as changing the PK as Solareflare suggested? Additionally and possibly irrelevantly when I try to drop this index MariaDB tells me `ERROR 1553 (HY000): Cannot drop index 'idx_format_id_card_id': needed in a foreign key constraint`. Which is really confusing as I literally just created it. Does that give us a hint about what is going wrong here?

Comment: The two foreign keys shown in CREATE TABLE are  CONSTRAINT `card_legality_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`card_id`) REFERENCES `card` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `card_legality_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`format_id`) REFERENCES `format` (`id`).

Comment: The MySQL version has the same behavior of refusing to drop the newly-created index with the same error. Curious.

Comment: OK ignore all that mess. I worked out that my new index displaced the index on format_id and if I add that back I'm then able to drop the new index. But it's still super curious that this makes things slower!

Comment: With both (format_id) and (format_id,card_id) indexes it performs in the same old 10s-ish.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` can be tricky from an optimization perspective.  I wonder if this works better on the two systems:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM _cache_card  c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM card_legality cl
              WHERE cl.card_id = c.id AND format_id = 35
             );
```

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to speed things up a smidge but not the orders of magnitude jump seen in the MySQL execution.

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker . . . I notice that the estimate of the number of rows in `_cache_card` is quite different in the two plans.  Perhaps the data is different on the two systems.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference started when MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 10.0 came out -- they had *separately* developed several improved optimizations.  You hit a construct involving `IN` where one made significant improvements that the other did not (an perhaps has not yet) picked up.

Avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )` whenever a `JOIN` is practical.

`EXISTS( SELECT 1 ... )` is another construct to experiment with.

Indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY on every table !
card_legality:  INDEX(format_id, card_id) -- in this order
_cache_card:  (id)  -- This seems like a serious omission !
```

Something that hurts performance:  using `*TEXT` when a smallish `VARCHAR` would suffice.

When timing, run the query twice.  The first gets things copied into RAM (buffer_pool); the second is realistic for comparison.

How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` for each?

Comment: The UNIQUE INDEX in Lukasz Szozda's answer fixed the performance on MariaDB but you're right that _cache_card is a bit of a mess. I will implement your changes to try and improve the other queries that use this table. The reason for the *TEXT column types and other nonsense is that this table is created with a SELECT INTO but worse case I can run one-off ALTER TABLE after generation. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: 3.8GB RAM, 4GB swap. innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728 FYI

Comment: For that much RAM, suggest buffer_pool of 600M.